# Enable the GPU of my laptop

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bios, gpu

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 - i7559 laptop with windows 10. It comes with a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M. But in my device manager, I only see Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 under the display adapters items. I even installed the latest NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M driver by myself. It driver is not able to recognize the card. After some research, it appears that the GPU might be turned off in BIOS. So I went to my BIOS, but was not able to find any option to turn any GPU on and off.

Why I cannot access the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M GPU? Some site suggests that the GTX 960M GPU might be integrated, and it is only running in the background, and I am not able to access it. But is there any way that I can access the GPU?

Here are my BIOS page.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What makes you believe you have a Nvidia GPU?  Did it work at any point?

Comment: go in device manager , select View ,  select Show hidden devices. Now u can see the gpu?

Comment: @Ramhound The is written on the official laptop specification that my laptop is shipped with the Nvidia GPU

Comment: Have you contacted Dell?  The reason I ask is that the Nvidia driver installer should have detected the hardware